# Getting attributes from cached service in ArcGIS Online?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-online

I have cached a service using ArcGIS Server 10.1.  This is from an mxd with 5 very large and dense vector layers.  This is used by a number of desktop users as a mapping service by connecting direclty to ArcGIS Server.  They are able to return the attributes of the features using the "info" button.  I now wish to add this service to an ArcGIS online map where a similar functionality is needed.  Is this possible?

I have tried enabling both wms and wfs as a capability in ArcGIS Server, as well as enabling a "dynamic workspace" however when I add my service to ArcGIS online I am unable to select a feature to view a pop-up window or an attribute table (I have no preference as to which one I want to be able to see).  I do not want the user to be able to edit the data.  I just need them to be able to click on a feature to view its information.

I have also tried enabling "feature access" as a capability in ArcGIS server.  This does indeed allow me to view the attribution, however it changes the styling of my data.  I'm assuming that this only supports basic fills and lines, whereas my data uses patterned fills and lines.

I have also published the same mxd as a non-cached service to ArcGIS online and I am able to click on a feature and get a pop-up showing me the attributes.  All the styling is also kept.

The problem with using a non-cached service is that it is extremely slow because there is so much data.

Am I trying to do the impossible?

I've thought of a workaround which I will try next.  This essentially relies on me publishing 2 services.  The first service would be the cached one with full styling (possibly as a basemap so it's faster).  The second service would be the same non-cahed data with no styling, so you can't see it, over the top.  Essentially a ghost service.  As there is no styling it shouldn't take as long to draw, but the attribution will be there.  From the user perspective they will just see the basemap layer and click on the features on there to see the attribution.

This could work, but it seems a bit of a long winded way as it relies on me publishing 2 services whereas I would like to be able to achieve this using a single cached service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to access the attributes of a cached MapService using popups.

**ArcGIS Online**

- add the cached MapService to a new Web Map.
- Expand the map service by clicking on it
- Click the drop down arrow beside the layer icon, and click 'Configure Pop-up'
- Configure the pop-up and save your changes

[image]

You can then query the cached map service by clicking on it.

[image]